# POWERSHELL - Output A Section of the Container/OU of AD-User Account's DistinguishedName

Tags: powershell, get-aduser

I was voluntold to learn powershell about a week ago, and learned a lot from here.
I was unable to find a method that worked for me so now I am posting my first question.

I am looking to output under the OU column, not the full DistinguishedName, but a piece of it only.

How would I assign specific part of the DistinguishedName to the OU?
Instead of "CN=*,OU=*,DC=*", I would only want "(Name of OU) under (Name of Parent OU)"

Input

```
$ADExtProps =
@(
'Enabled',
'SamAccountName',
'OU'
)

Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $TestOU -Properties $ADExtProps 
Format-Table $ADExtProps -AutoSize -Wrap
```

Output

```
Enabled SamAccountName OU
------- -------------- --
   True testuser04     {}
   True testuser05     {}
   True testuser01     {}
   True testuser02     {}
   True testuser03     {}
   True testuser06     {}
   True testuser07     {}
   True testuser08     {}
   True testuser09     {}
  False testuser10     {}
```

Thank you!

How would I assign specific part of the DistinguishedName to the OU?
Instead of "CN=*,OU=*,DC=*", I would only want "(Name of OU) under (Name of Parent OU)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be done with regex extracting the OU name from the user's `DistinguishedName` however for the sake of not overcomplicating it, you can first query all OUs using `Get-ADOrganizationalUnit` then those objects already have the OU `.Name` which you can use to construct your output:

```
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter * | ForEach-Object {
    $ouName = $_.Name
    Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $_.DistinguishedName -SearchScope OneLevel |
        Select-Object Enabled, SamAccountName, @{N='OU'; E={ $ouName }}
}
```

If you want to extract the OU common name using [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) the following should work:

```
$TestOU = 'OU=someOU,DC=someDomain,DC=com'
$re = [regex] '(?<=OU=).+?(?<!\\)(?=,)'
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $TestOU |
    Select-Object Enabled, SamAccountName, @{N='OU'; E={ $re.Match($_.DistinguishedName).Value }}
```